# References in csproj file not found when moved to another build environment

Tags: c#, reference, visual-studio-2019

So I created a project in my build environment and it includes references to external DLLs. After adding the references you can see the references in the .csproj file. After checking the code in, the code was checked out on the build machine. Attempt to build, we get errors about missing references to DLLs specified in the references. But the DLLs are there.

Next, we open the project in the VS GUI. Click the references tab, nothing. Added the references again by hand. Save and close VS and kick of the build. It works just fine. We do a diff of the directory tree containing the project and there are no changes. So VS is storing these references somewhere that isn't the .csproj file. Where?

Not being able to find this will make change management difficult.

Comment: Are you sure that the references are missing? Or could it be that the DLLs themselves are missing? Did you add the dlls to source control? Do they exist in the build machine after the code is cloned? And lastly, are you sure the referenced DLLs are x86 and x64 compatible? Is your build server building using the same architecture as you are when you are building locally?

Comment: The DLLs were there.

Comment: In that case I've never seen this happen, sorry i can't be of help.